# Does MultiColumnText Work in iTextSharp v5.3.3?

Tags: .net, itext

I can't find `MultiColumnText` anywhere in iTextSharp v5.3.3 (from NuGet). All I can find is `ColumnText` which certainly isn't as friendly to use and is more than I really need. Am I missing something? There are several links that say that `MultiColumnText` should exist.

- http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/MultiColumnText.html
- [itextsharp nextcolumn not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759967/itextsharp-nextcolumn-not-working)
- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/89/iTextSharp-Page-Layout-with-Columns
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/Adding-Columns-With-iTextSharp/

Comment: MultiColumnText was removed for iText and iTextSharp. You should use ColumnText instead.

Comment: @Bruno, add that as an answer and I'll mark you correct. Also, if anyone knows of a custom implementation of `MultiColumnText`, I'd appreciate knowing about it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While iTextSharp doesn't include `MultiColumnText`, I could still 'roll my own'. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781862/271351