# Set background color to PARAGRAPH using itextSharp version 4 neither CHUNK nor entire pages only for paragraph using C#

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have tried to apply background color on paragraph using C# and iTextSharp version 4 not able to do. While applying background to CHUNK, it is applying only for text's background but not paragraph background.

Please check below snapshots and suggest.

[image: Data flow in multiple columns]
[image: Data flow in sigle column]

Comment: Please share code to reproduce the issue. And please be aware that this might be a deficiency of the old itextsharp version you use, so the proposed solutions might be "update!"...

Comment: Not able to upload full load here please check below link Using similar approach -  https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/89/itextsharp-page-layout-with-columns

Comment: Latest version is not supporting MultiColumnText becuase this feature I am going to use itextSharp other rich pdf generation libs(Apose PDF) don't have this feature please suggest - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774040/does-multicolumntext-work-in-itextsharp-v5-3-3